# Redux reducers adding a value to complex multidimensional object

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

i have an object in my initialState in redux reducer.The object is multidimesional.the object is like below

```
tradings: {
    'buy': {
        data: []
    },
    'sell': {
        data: []
    },
    'total': {
        data: []
    }
},
```

So when i want to reduce an action payload (`i.e: '1212'`) how i can push item into data array?

for example:

```
case 'EXCHANGE_BUY' : {
        return{
            ...state,
            tradings: state.tradings['buy'].data.concat(action.payload)
        }
    }
```

But it only returns an array like this: `tradings: ['1212']` How can i get like this>

```
tradings: {
'buy': {
    data: ['1212']
},
'sell': {
    data: []
},
'total': {
    data: []
}
```

},

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you clone every level of your redux reducers state.  You can do it like this:

```
case 'EXCHANGE_BUY' : {
        return{
            ...state,
            tradings: {
               ...state.tradings,
               buy: {
                 data: state.tradings.buy.data.concat(action.payload)
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 case 'EXCHANGE_BUY':
      return {
        ...state,
        tradings: {
          ...state.tradings,
          buy: {
            data: {
               state.tradings.buy.data.concat(action.payload)
              }
           }
        }
     }
```

Or the second approach you can use is [Immutability helpers](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper).

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use the spread operator to clone until the level is reached:

```
case 'EXCHANGE_BUY' : {
   return{
      ...state,
      tradings: {
        ...state.tradings,
        buy : {
          data: [...state.tradings.buy.data, action.payload]
         }
      }
   }
}
```